# IF Generator Expression with Option as parameter

Tags: cmake

I have a script (CMake 3.12) which looks a bit like this (superfluous stuff removed):

```
option(XXH_D_FNF "" OFF)
...
target_compile_definitions(xxh PRIVATE $<IF:XXH_D_FNF, XXH_FORCE_NATIVE_FORMAT, > XXH_FORCE_MEMORY_ACCESS=${XXH_D_FMA})
```

with the intention being that the preprocessor definition `XXH_FORCE_NATIVE_FORMAT` be added to the `target_compile_defintions` iff the associated option is set to `ON`, otherwise remained undefined. However, this gives me the error:

```
First parameter to $<IF> must resolve to exactly one '0' or '1' value.
```

Which isn't fixed by wrapping `XXH_D_FNF` in a `${}`. How do I use this option's value as the condition in this expression?

Comment: Anything wrong with `if (XXH_D_FNF) target_compile_definitions(xxh PRIVATE XXH_FORCE_NATIVE_FORMAT)` which is more readable, maintanable, etc? why would you use generator expression for this?

Comment: I have a few more definitions, some of which require values setting, I'll update the OP

Comment: So anything wrong with `target_compile_definitions(xxh PRIVATE XXH_FORCE_MEMORY_ACCESS=${XXH_D_FMA})` `if (XXH_D_FNF)` `target_compile_definitions(xxh PRIVATE XXH_FORCE_NATIVE_FORMAT)`?

Comment: Ah I didn't realise calls to `target_compile_definitions` were cumulative, that should do

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for [conditional](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#conditional-expressions) generator expressions (which includes those using `IF`) says:

```
$<IF:condition,true_string,false_string>
```

> Evaluates to `true_string` if `condition` is `1`. Otherwise evaluates to `false_string`.
>   Typically, the `condition` is a **boolean generator expression**.

So, your condition *itself* must be a [boolean](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#logical-operators) generator expression. So if we wrap `XXH_D_FNF` in a boolean generator expression, we would use `$<BOOL:${XXH_D_FNF}>`. This would evaluate to `false` when the option is `OFF`, otherwise it would be `true`.

Hence, your full call to `target_compile_definitions` would look something like this:

```
target_compile_definitions(xxh PRIVATE $<IF:$<BOOL:${XXH_D_FNF}>, XXH_FORCE_NATIVE_FORMAT, > XXH_FORCE_MEMORY_ACCESS=${XXH_D_FMA})
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to use generator expressions here. `target_compile_definitions` and all similar interfaces are cumulative. Just:

```
target_compile_definitions(xxh PRIVATE XXH_FORCE_MEMORY_ACCESS=${XXH_D_FMA}) 
if (XXH_D_FNF) 
   target_compile_definitions(xxh PRIVATE XXH_FORCE_NATIVE_FORMAT)
endif()
```